# sbt immediately stops when running in docker container

Tags: docker, sbt

I'm trying to set up our project to use Docker. I've created an image based on this image: https://github.com/mozilla/docker-sbt.

The command in my docker-compose.yml file is:

```
sbt -J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=500m -Dlogger.file=conf/dev-logback.xml -Dconfig.file=$dev -Dhttp.port=$srfPort -Dhttps.port=9443 -Djdbcdslog.showTime=true -J-Dakka.http.parsing.max-uri-length=16k run
```

(this command works in the non-docker environment.)

Below is the output of `docker-compose up`. Notice that right after it starts it says "Stopping server...". When I watch the console I notice that there is no pause between the "Listening" line and the "stopping" line.

```
[info] Loading settings for project my-project from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:/home/my-name/my-project/app/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTPS on /0.0.0.0:9443

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server...
[warn] StaticRoutesGenerator is deprecated. Please use InjectedRoutesGenerator or a custom router instead.
[warn] For more info see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting#Dependency-Injection
[warn] StaticRoutesGenerator is deprecated. Please use InjectedRoutesGenerator or a custom router instead.
[warn] For more info see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting#Dependency-Injection
2020-04-07 21:32:10,984~[WARN]~Logger configuration in conf files is deprecated and has no effect. Use a logback configuration file instead.~
2020-04-07 21:32:14,313~[INFO]~Slf4jLogger started~
2020-04-07 21:32:15,413~[INFO]~Database [default] initialized at jdbc:mysql://srf_db:3306/srf2?socketTimeout=10000&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false~
2020-04-07 21:32:15,481~[INFO]~Creating Pool for datasource 'default'~
2020-04-07 21:32:15,514~[INFO]~HikariPool-1 - Starting...~
2020-04-07 21:32:16,066~[INFO]~HikariPool-1 - Start completed.~
2020-04-07 21:32:40,261~[INFO]~Application started (Dev)~
2020-04-07 21:32:40,319~[INFO]~Shutting down connection pool.~
2020-04-07 21:32:40,334~[INFO]~HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...~
2020-04-07 21:32:40,366~[INFO]~HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.~

[success] Total time: 140 s (02:20), completed Apr 8, 2020 1:32:40 AM
```

I have no idea where to look for the error or what the nature of the error could be: a missing file? a missing folder? a missing dependency? a missing setup command? permission error?

I am at a loss for how to debug further. If you have any guesses about where to look, it would be greatly appreciated.

[edit]

Thanks to a hint from cbley below, I figured out what my docker-compose.yml file needs to look like:

```
  sbt:
    image: my-image
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - USER
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/docker1/
    command: bash -c "sbt etc..."
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9443:9443"
```

Notice the added `stdin_open` and `tty` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a Play service interactively (in development mode), it waits for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When inside the container, standard input is not connected to a TTY and thus the read from standard input fails immediately which causes the server to stop, which also exits SBT since the `run` task was the only one.

You can build a Docker image from your Play service by running `sbt docker:publishLocal`. (there's no need to have SBT inside the container)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what's happening. But my whole purpose if creating this docker image is so that I don't need to install sbt on my computer. I want the development environment completely contained so that an OS update doesn't break anything and/or I can give this to someone else and not make them install a bunch of developer tools.

Comment: Thank you again! You steered me right. I needed to add `stdin_open: true
    tty: true` to my docker-compose.yml file. I'll edit my question above for posterity.